# Does grid inline editing support dropdown?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Currently editor property of kendo-grid-column supports numeric, text and boolean values. Is it possible to have dropdown control inside grid cell in edit mode?

Answer (score 1):

Another example using reactive forms:

Define your list values in your component.ts file:

```
public listItems: Array<string> = ["Product1", "Product2"];
```

You can then use it like this:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="ProductName">
            <template kendoGridEditTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">
                     <kendo-dropdownlist [data]="listItems [value]="dataItem.ProductName"  (valueChange)="handleValueChange($event)></kendo-dropdownlist>
            </template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

Then in your component you need to provide handleValueChange definition.

```
handleValueChange(value) {
        this.formGroup.get('ProductName').setValue(value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a template and put whatever you need:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Product Name">
    <template kendoGridEditTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">
        <kendo-dropdownlist [(ngModel)]="dataItem.itemId" [data]="listItems"></kendo-dropdownlist>
    </template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```